# Global Notifications View using Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a notification view responsible for displaying global messages at the top of the page (info, warning, confirmation messages ...)

I created a NotificationView for the purpose, defined its content property and provided two  handlers to show and hide the view.

```
APP.NotificationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'notification',
    classNames:['nNote'],
    content:null,

    didInsertElement : function(){                
    },

    click: function() {
        var _self = this;
        _self.$().fadeTo(200, 0.00, function(){ //fade
            _self.$().slideUp(200, function() { //slide up                    
                _self.$().remove(); //then remove from the DOM
            });
        });
       _self.destroy();
    },

    show: function() {
        var _self = this;
        _self.$().css('display','block').css('opacity', 0).slideDown('slow').animate(
            { opacity: 1 },
            { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
        );          
    }
});
```

Ideally, i should be able to send an event from any controller or route to show the view with the proper content and styling. What would be the best way to architect this

I thought of using a named outlet in my application's template, however outlets are not quite suited for dynamic views.

```
<div id="content">
    {{outlet notification}}
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

I was also thinking of architecting the notification view to be a response to "The application" or "A Module" state.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because you have animations you want to run when the notifications change, you will want to create a subclass of `Ember.View` (a "widget"):

```
App.NotificationView = Ember.View.extend({
  notificationDidChange: function() {
    if (this.get('notification') !== null) {
      this.$().slideDown();
    }
  }.observes('notification'),

  close: function() {
    this.$().slideUp().then(function() {
      self.set('notification', null);
    });
  },

  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(
    "<button {{action 'close' target='view'}}>Close</button>" +
    "{{view.notification}}"
  )
});
```

This widget will expect to have a `notification` property. You can set it from your `application` template:

```
{{view App.NotificationView id="notifications" notificationBinding="notification"}}
```

This will gets its `notification` property from the `ApplicationController`, so we will create a couple of methods on the controller that other controllers can use to send notifications:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  closeNotification: function() {
    this.set('notification', null);
  },

  notify: function(notification) {
    this.set('notification', notification);
  }
});
```

Now, let's say we want to create a notification every time we enter the `dashboard` route:

```
App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    var notification = "You have entered the dashboard";
    this.controllerFor('application').notify(notification);
  }
});
```

The view itself manages the DOM, while the application controller manages the `notification` property. You can see it all working [at this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uqafis/3/edit).

Note that if all you wanted to do was display a notification, and didn't care about animations, you could just have done:

```
{{#if notification}}
  <div id="notification">
    <button {{action "closeNotification"}}>Close</button>
    <p id="notification">{{notification}}</p>
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

in your `application` template, with the same `ApplicationController`, and everything would just work.

Comment: Sometimes i need to show notification from the controller. Since `Cotroller#controllerFor` method is deprecated, i cannot do `this.controllerFor('application').notify(notification);` from a controller. Is it correct way to have event 'notify' in `App.ApplicationRoute`, and do `this.send('notify')` from a controller.

Comment: I am aware of `needs` in controller, but i am wondering about defining `needs` in all the controllers.

Comment: I also found [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Faaronvb.com%2Farticles%2F49-ember-js-flash-messages&ei=gHqnUpCWL4mxrQHrvYA4&usg=AFQjCNGMo817jxSuu2lwx88ny3D8IIWfXg&bvm=bv.57799294,d.aWM) link useful concerning some updates to Ember.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that Notifications should be a View, I think they should be a Component. Then they are also more flexible to be used across your application.

You could a Notification Component **instead** as answered here: [How can I make an Alert Notifications component using Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070102/how-can-i-make-an-alert-notifications-component-using-ember-js/)

Comment: Agreed, but the original answer was before components :) Component + Service